# How to implement strong server-side account passwords with user-friendly client side passwords

Tags: .net, security, encryption

I have a requirement to allow users to use a 4+ numeric pin style password on a single device. Obviously this is a bad password to be used directly to protect their server side account, so I want to 'lock' this PIN to the specific device, so that someone must have both the PIN and device to login, and where gaining access to the device does not give access to the PIN. Also, they already have a more conventional username/pw login, and by signing up on a device they are adding a new set of login credentials to this existing account. So this is my current plan:

1. During the local device signup process, locally generate a strong password.
2. Send this generated strong password to the server as their server-side device specific account password.
3. Use their supplied 4+ digit password to locally symmetrically encrypt the strong generated password.
4. Store this encrypted strong password on the local device.
5. During subsequent logins on that device, the user supplies the same 4+ digit password, it is used to decrypt the previously stored strong password, and the strong password is sent off to the server for login.

So I believe this achieves the strong server side password requirement. However I also need to protect as best I can against compromised client devices *after the signup process* (devices compromised before/during the signup process are a lost cause). Obviously with a 4 digit encryption key, there are only 10,000 possible combinations, so an attacker will easily be able to try every combination on the locally encrypted strong password very quickly. **What I want to know is do I have to choose a specific symmetric encryption scheme and/or generated password format so that the attacker will not be able to tell from local data alone which of the 10k decryption attempts was the correct one?** i.e. He would still have to attempt each of the 10k passwords on the server-side login.

Also, is there anything glaringly wrong with this approach, or a more standard approach to achieving these requirements? If there is a standard approach, is there a standard .NET library for this approach?

Comment: That's a good idea.  How do you intend to handle "forgot password scenarios?

Comment: @SLaks The user also has a more conventional email/password account on the server that they can access from anywhere, with the normal forgot password system. I don't intend to handle the forgot device pin scenario. If they do forget their device specific PIN, then they have to re-associate that device by running through the same device signup process as before.

Comment: You might want to lock the account after x failed logins; forcing the user to reset their password (i.e trough mail)

Comment: @Zar Yes, that's the plan. But that is pointless if the attacker with the compromised device can decrypt all 10k options, and know locally which one is correct without having to trial and error each one. He then logs in with that and gets it on the first attempt.

Comment: You are better off if you simply don't allow more than X login attempts, saving the password server side using PBKDF2 (or bcrypt or scrypt). You can do the same thing for the longer password in case the user is locked out. For transport protection of the plain password use TLS, only perform PBKDF2 (with a random salt and iteration count) server side.

Comment: @owlstead But that gives an attacker with access to the server login service (i.e. anyone with the internet) an X/10000 chance of gaining access to someone elses account. With my approach (assuming there is an answer to my bolded question), it only gives an attacker with access to someone elses local device a X/10000 chance of gaining access. Well that is how I see it, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah, in that case store a salt in the local device and calculate key1 using PBKDF2. Then use that key server side to calculate key2, using a separately stored salt. As key1 is never stored, the attacker does not have the required information.

Comment: @owlstead Ahh thanks, that's much nicer! One thing to check (I'm pretty sure its safe but just want to make sure), it sort of leads us back to the original question: If an attacker does gain access to a device, knowing that the password is only 4 digits, and with access to the salt, is there any requirements on the salt's length/entropy and on the choice of hashing algorithms to prevent the attacker from 'knowing' that one of the 10k generated hashes is the correct one without sending it to the server?

Comment: @owlstead Your most recent comment is basically the answer to my question, atleast my second question of 'is there a more standard approach?'. Did you want to put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Can you explain to us, a little better, what it is you're trying to achieve? Does the server normally perform authentication against the password and your only concern is to implement a secondary "simple" password so people can use that in lieu of a password when using a mobile device?

Comment: @Nik edited the first paragraph to clarify the requirements more, but basically, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store a salt in the local device and calculate key1 using PBKDF2. Then use that key server side to calculate key2, using a separately stored salt. As key1 is never stored, the attacker does not have the required information.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is "bad" because no matter how "strong" the encryption that you use is the keyspace that an attacker has to search is very small. Even with 8-digit numeric passwords, there are only 10^8 or one hundred million possible keys.

My approach would be different. I'd start by asking "why store *any* credentials at all on the device?" I don't believe there's a good answer to that question.

Instead consider this solution:

The user wants to activate a PIN. First, he chooses the PIN; let's call his choice N. He contacts your web service, identifies himself with his username and password and sends N.

On the server side, you generate a random string, let's call it X. You concatenate X and N, and then hash that using something like SHA-256. Let's call the result H. The server now stores (X, H). Notice that your server does *not* store the PIN.

Later on, when the user opens up the mobile device and puts in his PIN, the device contacts your web service and says: "I'm about to perform a PIN auth for user 'Nik Bougalis'. Give me a challenge!"

The server creates a state for this authentication: It locates the account record, and finds the X value and sends to the user "X,R" where R is a random number that is generated for this state.

The user puts his PIN in, let's call it P. The mobile device now concatenates X and P, and hashes the result using the same algorithm the server uses, generating H. It now combines H and R, and hashes the result. This generates a new hash, let's call it V.

The mobile device sends V to the server. The server combines the H value from the database and the R associated with the state, hashes the combination and compares it to V. If they match, the PIN entered in the mobile device is correct and you grant the user access. If they don't match, the PIN entered is incorrect.

This method has the advantage that the server can rate-limit authentication attempts and slow down brute force attacks. It can even lock an account down after too many unsuccessful attempts, requiring the password to unlock it.

If you are doing this whole exchange over SSL, you can skip sending the random value R, although the computational cost is so little that I'd just include it anyways.

A potential disadvantage is that the user cannot "login" using a PIN if the device cannot talk to the server. I don't know if you have a requirement to allow offline logins, but depending on your particular app and market, this may not be a big deal - some may even call it an advantage.

To be clear, this isn't a "super bullet-proof solution". If someone breaks in and gains access to the table holding the H values they can impersonate the user without knowing the PIN. If that's a concern, there are some workarounds there.

If you are really interested in very high security (and I doubt you are, since you are contemplating 4-digit PINs) there are more advanced algorithms that could be used to perform zero-knowledge proofs of identity.

Comment: Thanks Nik, not sure if I'm misunderstanding something, but your basically just describing a normal salted and hashed password scheme aren't you? N is the password, X is the salt, and H is the hash. With this approach anyone with access to the server (anyone with access to the internet) and someone else's user ID can start guessing passwords, and when passwords are 4 digit numerics there is a high chance of getting it correct. I am trying to associate a PIN with specific device, so that an attacker must guess the PIN AND have access to the specific device to login.

Comment: Ok, not quite a 'normal salted and hashed password scheme', as you also hash client side to protect against transmitting the password in the clear after the initial signup, but still, it doesn't tie that PIN to any specific device.

Comment: You need to decide what side you trust: the mobile device or the server. The server, presumably, already has the user's information. My solution was devised to obviate the need to store anything at all on the mobile device, thus making a stolen mobile device worthless by allowing the server to control and throttle authentication requests. If someone breaks into the server it's game over. But in that case, it would be game over anyways, regardless of the solution.

Comment: Ahh I see where your coming from. I obviously trust the server more, but the device specific PIN doesn't give full access to the user account, only to a subset specific to the device. So I don't mind a stolen device increasing the chances of an attacker gaining access to the subset specific to that device, as the user can always block that specific device from their full login. I'm just trying to still make it as hard as possible for an attacker. Basically for a 4 digit PIN, give them an X/10000 chance (where X is number of failed attempts before the device specific login is blocked).

Comment: I just think it's a bad idea to encrypt the password with a key that has so little entropy that it might as well not be there... Again, if you can assume the mobile device can access your server over the Internet, then there shouldn't be any need to store *anything* at all.

Comment: But there is, to make something specific to that device, so an attacker must have the device along with the PIN. Otherwise fake device logins can be spoofed from all over the world with various PIN attempts. I'm pretty sure owlstead's answer achieves this, can you comment on that?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to achieve. You're trying to use the device to do "poor-man's two-factor authentication". The solution by owlstead should work; the solution I outlined will also work, with trivial modifications (i.e. having the mobile device generate and send an additional random string during signup).

Comment: Haha yes, exactly, good way of putting it! Cheers for the help.